# FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation is always null, even onCreated()

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, android-fusedlocation

I'm asking about receiving **FINE** and **COARSE** permissions successfully. Then building `GoogleAPIClient` and creating `LocationRequest` but then `FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation` it keeps on returning null. I am aware that the connection should be established before asking for a location. Because `onStart()` where the Connection is established is called after `retrieveLocation()` method I call `mLocationApiClient.connect()` immediately after building `GoogleApiClient. onConnected` method is being hit and when I check mLocationApiClient.isConnected() it says 'true'. And then when I try to retrieve `LastLocation` using `FusedLocationApi` it always return null. I feel confused because I've checked multiple times and there is a connection but no location retrieved. Where am I wrong?

MainActivity:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
public class MainActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
     GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

        private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 7171;
        private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 7172;
        private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000; // seconds
        private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 3000; // seconds
        private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10; // meters

        private LocationRequest mLocatiionRequest;
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private Location mLastLocation;

    @AfterViews
    void retrieveLocation() {
        int fineLocationPermission = 
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        int coarseLocationPermission = 
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

        if (fineLocationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && coarseLocationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        this.requestPermissions(
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                             Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
        );
    } else {
        if (this.isPlayServiceAvailable()) {
            this.buildGoogleApiClient();
            this.createLocationRequest();

            this.mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(this.mGoogleApiClient);

            String message = "";
            if (this.mLastLocation != null)
                message = "Lat: " + this.mLastLocation.getLatitude() + ", Lon: " + this.mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            else
                message = "Didn't manage to get location.";

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (this.isPlayServiceAvailable())
                    this.buildGoogleApiClient();
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    this.retrieveLocation();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    this.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.mLastLocation = location;
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (this.mGoogleApiClient != null)
        this.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(this.mGoogleApiClient, this);
    if (this.mGoogleApiClient != null)
        this.mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

private boolean isPlayServiceAvailable() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The device is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    if (this.mGoogleApiClient == null) // avoid recreating client when it is already connected
        this.mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

    if (!this.mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) // avoid unwanted hitting of onConnect callback
        this.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

private void createLocationRequest() {
    this.mLocatiionRequest = new LocationRequest();
    this.mLocatiionRequest.setInterval(this.UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    this.mLocatiionRequest.setFastestInterval(this.FATEST_INTERVAL);
    this.mLocatiionRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    this.mLocatiionRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(this.DISPLACEMENT);
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    int fineLocationPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    int coarseLocationPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

    if (fineLocationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && coarseLocationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(this.mGoogleApiClient, this.mLocatiionRequest, this);
}

private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(this.mGoogleApiClient, this);
}
```

}

Build.graddle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

def AAVersion = '4.3.1'

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.mosy.kalin.mosy'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mosy.mosyandroid"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
    {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Just because you connected to Play Services does not necessarily mean that there is a location. `getLastLocation()` is a fine optimization, but you need to be prepared for it to return `null` while Play Services is figuring out where the device is.

Comment: Great. I will take care for the case when LastLocation is null, I promise. But then how am I supposed to test the case when LastLocation is not null if I am not able to retrieve it. How can I be sure if Google Play service is able to figure out where the device is (as you've mentioned).

Comment: "But then how am I supposed to test the case when LastLocation is not null if I am not able to retrieve it" -- you register for location updates, and use the first update that you receive.

Comment: Is there a possibillity I've missed something while setting up the Play service? And can't I somehow force receiving a location?

Comment: "can't I somehow force receiving a location?" -- well, no. After all, mobile devices are powered by batteries. Continuously monitoring for location drains the battery. Hence, mobile devices do not do this. They only monitor for locations sporadically or if an app specifically requests location updates. On Android 8.0+, even if apps request location updates, the device will check less frequently, if those apps are all in the background. So, request location updates, and react when you have one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 Reson for this

1. getLastLocation() not give location always. You have to write location update also
2. In some devices some times google play service won't connect

So for avoid this you have to fetch location from GPS also, consider following code

add this dependencies in your build gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
```

Add this Class for getting location -- LocationResolver.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;


import cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog;

import static android.content.Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;



public class LocationResolver implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, android.location.LocationListener {

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters
    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 ; // 1 minute

    //Location Request code
    private final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 2;
    //Google Api Client
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    //Location request for google fused location Api
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    //Location manager for location services
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;

    private OnLocationResolved mOnLocationResolved;

    private Activity mActivity;

    //Location permission Dialog
    private SweetAlertDialog mDialog;

    public LocationResolver(Activity activity){
        mActivity=activity;
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    public void resolveLocation(Activity activity, OnLocationResolved onLocationResolved){
        this.mOnLocationResolved = onLocationResolved;
        this.mActivity=activity;

        if (isEveryThingEnabled()){
            startLocationPooling();
        }
    }

    public interface OnLocationResolved{
        void onLocationResolved(Location location);
    }


    /*
  * Checking every criteria are enabled for getting location from device
  * */
    public boolean isEveryThingEnabled() {
        if (!isLocationPermissionEnabled()) {
            showPermissionRequestDialog();
            return false;
        } else if (!isLocationEnabled(mActivity)) {
            showLocationSettingsDialog();
            return false;
        } else if (!isConnected()) {
            showWifiSettingsDialog(mActivity);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    /*
   * This function checks if location permissions are granted or not
   * */
    public boolean isLocationPermissionEnabled() {

        return !(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }


    /*
    * Previous location permissions were denied , this function opens app settings page
    * So user can enable permission manually
    * */
    private void startAppDetailsActivity() {

        final Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + mActivity.getPackageName()));

        mActivity.startActivity(i);
    }



    private void showLocationSettingsDialog() {
        SweetAlertDialog builder = new SweetAlertDialog(mActivity, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE);
        builder.setTitleText("Need Location");
        builder.setContentText("In order for the app to work seamlessly.Please  enable Location Service.");
        builder.setConfirmText("Enable");
        builder.setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog dialog) {
                dialog.cancel();
                startLocationSettings();
            }
        });
        builder.setCancelText("Cancel");
        builder.setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog dialog) {
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }

    private void startLocationSettings() {
        mActivity.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
    }

    /*
    * location permissions were denied with "do not show"  unchecked.. this function shows a dialog describing why this app
    * need location permission.
    * */
    private void showPermissionRequestDialog() {
        if (mDialog != null)
            mDialog.cancel();
        mDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(mActivity, SweetAlertDialog.NORMAL_TYPE);
        mDialog.setTitleText("You need location permission");
        mDialog.setContentText("Enable location permission");
        mDialog.setConfirmText("grant");
        mDialog.setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog dialog) {
                dialog.cancel();
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
        });
        mDialog.setCancelText("Cancel");
        mDialog.setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog dialog) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        mDialog.show();
    }

    /*
    *
    *
    *  Previously Permission Request was cancelled with 'Dont Ask Again',
    *  Redirect to Settings after showing Information about why you need the permission
    *
    * */
    private void showPermissionDeniedDialog() {

        if (mDialog != null)
            mDialog.cancel();
        mDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(mActivity, SweetAlertDialog.NORMAL_TYPE);
        mDialog.setTitleText("Need Location Permission");


        mDialog.setContentText("Enable location permission");
        mDialog.setConfirmText("grant");
        mDialog.setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog dialog) {
                dialog.cancel();
                startAppDetailsActivity();
            }
        });
        mDialog.setCancelText("Cancel");
        mDialog.setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog dialog) {
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });

        mDialog.show();
    }


    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    startLocationPooling();
                } else {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(mActivity,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(mActivity,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                        showPermissionRequestDialog();

                    } else {
                        showPermissionDeniedDialog();

                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }

    /*
    * Starting location pooling
    * */
    public void startLocationPooling() {


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

            return;

        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {
            mOnLocationResolved.onLocationResolved(location);
        } else {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())//if googleClient can get location from device the go for location update
                startLocationUpdates();
            else getLocation(); //Google Client cannot connected to its server. so we are fetching location directly from device
        }

    }

    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }



    public void onDestroy() {

        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    public void onStop() {
        if (mDialog != null) {
            mDialog.cancel();
        }
        stopLocationUpdates();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    public void onStart() {

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        // startLocationPooling();

    }

    /*
   * checks whether the device connected or not*/
    public boolean isConnected() {
        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
           mOnLocationResolved.onLocationResolved(location);
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }



    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(mActivity, ConnectionResult.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("TAG", "Location services connection failed with code==>" + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
            Log.e("TAG", "Location services connection failed Because of==> " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
        }

    }

    private void createLocationRequest() {
        Log.i("TAG", "CreateLocationRequest");
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000;
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 10000;
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        //**************************
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
        //**************************

    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {

        Log.i("TAG", "StartLocationUpdates");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                        mLocationRequest, this);

            }
        } else {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationRequest, this);
        }

    }

    private void stopLocationUpdates() {

        try {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);

            if (mLocationManager != null) {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void getLocation() {
        try {


            // getting GPS status
            Boolean isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            Boolean isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                Log.e("Location", "No provider enabled");
            } else {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                Location location = null;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    if (mLocationManager != null) {
                        location = mLocationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                           mOnLocationResolved.onLocationResolved(location);
                        } else {
                            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("Network", "Network");
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        if (mLocationManager != null) {
                            location = mLocationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                mOnLocationResolved.onLocationResolved(location);
                            } else {
                                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                                Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    /*
   * checks whether the device connected or not*/
    public static boolean isNetWorkConnected(Context  context) {
        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public   void showWifiSettingsDialog(final Context  context) {
        SweetAlertDialog builder = new SweetAlertDialog(context, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE);
        builder.setTitleText("Need Internet");
        builder.setContentText("Please enable your internet connection");

        builder.setConfirmText("Enable");
        builder.setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog dialog) {
                dialog.cancel();
                startWifiSettings(context);
            }
        });
        builder.setCancelText("Cancel");
        builder.setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog dialog) {
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });

        builder.show();

    }

    private   void startWifiSettings(Context context) {
        try {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {
        int locationMode = 0;
        String locationProviders;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            try {
                locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

            } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;

        } else {
            locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
            return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
        }
    }


}
```

In your activity follow these step

Create and initialize LocationResolver variable

```
  private LocationResolver mLocationResolver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mLocationResolver=new LocationResolver(this);

}
```

And also add these lines into your activity

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mLocationResolver.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mLocationResolver.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mLocationResolver.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    mLocationResolver.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Usage: When ever you want  location use this code for getting location

```
    void retrieveLocation() {

 mLocationResolver.resolveLocation(this, new LocationResolver.OnLocationResolved() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResolved(Location location) {
                // Do what ever you want
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! I'll try the enhancements you are proposing and will share my feedback.

Comment: By the way is there a reason for downgrading the google-location-api version? As you can see, I am already using v11.0.4

Comment: You can use 11.0.4 . no problem

Comment: In the `createLocationRequest` method your are configuring a `LocationSettingsRequest.Builder` without using the result with `build()`.