# Google Play Services not found / error

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I am trying to get user's current location. But in order to do this, I need the Google Play Service to be enabled in my code. So I check the `checkPlayService()` method first in my code before I am able to do execute further code such as find the user's current location. My code mostly follows [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/) tutorial.

The issue is that every time my code it returns the `Device is not supported.` toast, which may imply that I have not set up Google Play Services correctly in my android studio, or may something be wrong with my code? I know there are many questions on this already but no answer seems to solve it for me, at least for the ones I saw. Please help, I have tried every thing.

I have these lines in my AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="replaced_my_actual_key_with_this_statement" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

My Dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
```

My SDK installations looks like [image: this]

Code:

```
public class FindLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private TextView selectLocation;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_TO_ACCESS_LOCATION = 1;

    private LocationManager lm;
    private boolean gps_enabled = false;
    private boolean network_enabled = false;

    private Location mLastLocation;
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_location);

        lm = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        selectLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectLocation);

        if (checkPlayServices()) {

            // Building the GoogleApi client
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        }

        getCurrentLocation();

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        checkPlayServices();
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("THIS", "Permission NOT Granted!");

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},PERMISSION_REQUEST_TO_ACCESS_LOCATION);
            return;
        }
        Log.i("THIS", "Permission GRANTED!");

        isLocationEnabled();

        displayLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_TO_ACCESS_LOCATION: {
                Log.i("THIS", "Permission Deciding...");
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getCurrentLocation();
                } else {
                    Log.i("THIS", "Permission DENIED!");
                    // Permission denied, boo!
                    // Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }

            // Add further 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        }
    }

    public void isLocationEnabled() {
        try {
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch(Exception ex) {}

        try {
            network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch(Exception ex) {}

        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
            // notify user
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setMessage("Location Service not enabled!");
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    //get gps
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
                googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            }

            return false;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            finish();
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void displayLocation() {

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);    // ALLOWED

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            selectLocation.setText(latitude + ", " + longitude);

        } else {

            selectLocation.setText("(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        displayLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e("THIS", "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: try this answer..and remove meta data from your manifest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699971/fusedlocationapi-getlastlocation-is-always-null-even-oncreated/45705593#45705593

Comment: For your answer in the link, should there be a public for the retrieveLocation() method? Also, I am relatively new to android, so I see the onLocationResolved() and would like to display my location, say on a TextView. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It was actually just a silly mistake.

I copied the code from the tutorial I was referring to without realising that there was a slight bug (at least for my application) in the if else statement under the `checkPlayServices()` method. The corrected code is shown below.

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                        .show();
                Log.i("THISS", "HII_1");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Device Not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699971/fusedlocationapi-getlastlocation-is-always-null-even-oncreated/45705593#45705593) answer.

When ever you want your location . Use below code to retrieve  location and show this to your textview

```
mLocationResolver.resolveLocation(this, new LocationResolver.OnLocationResolved() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResolved(Location location) {
                // Do what ever you want
              textview.setText("latitude : " +location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude : "+ location.getLongitude() + "");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I have found the solution to my main question, and I have posted it. But I will upvote this as it answered my comment.