# Current Location not auto display to the textview

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

Currently I want to get the user current location of latitude and longitude but my code can get until I pressed the send button in the emulator setting but what I want is to auto get the location and set it to the textview so what should I do? Anyone please advice me to solve this problem please because I really not familiar with the location code.

Here's my code

```
package com.example.rex.ota30;

import android.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import static com.example.rex.ota30.R.id.textView;

public class Search extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

private FirebaseDatabase db;
private DatabaseReference sref, lref;
private TextView searchun, searchlo, searchla;
private String un, la, lo;
private LocationManager lm;
private LocationListener ll;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    sref = db.getReference("users");
    lref = db.getReference("userslocation");

    searchun = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sun);
    Intent i = this.getIntent();
    un = i.getStringExtra("username");
    searchun.setText(un);

    searchlo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.slo);
    searchla = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sla);

    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    la = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
    searchla.setText(la);

    lo = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    searchlo.setText(lo);

    lref.child(un).child("latitude").setValue(la);
    lref.child(un).child("longitude").setValue(lo);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","disable");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","enable");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d("Latitude","status");
}
}
```

Here's the sample of the getting location.
[image]

Comment: yes in emulator you need to set Latitude and Longitude first

Comment: or check on real device

Comment: But I thought the emulator already got the location?

Comment: no AFAIK i think we need to set the location to the emulator then it act like a real device for location.

Comment: try this answer for getting location  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699971/fusedlocationapi-getlastlocation-is-always-null-even-oncreated?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnLocationChanged is only called when the location has changed.
So the location is displayed in the Textview only when the send button is pressed.
If you want to display the location from the beginning, try this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) this);
  ...
  // add code
  Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
  la = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
  searchla.setText(la);

  lo = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
  searchlo.setText(lo);
}
```

Comment: why currently cannot run ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //Initializing googleApiClient
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
       // googleMapOptions.mapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID)
                    //    .compassEnabled(true);

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng india = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(india).title("Marker in India"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(india));
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    }

    //Getting current location
    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        mMap.clear();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {
            //Getting longitude and latitude
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();

            //moving the map to location
            moveMap();
        }
    }

    private void moveMap() {
        /**
         * Creating the latlng object to store lat, long coordinates
         * adding marker to map
         * move the camera with animation
         */
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(true)
                .title("Marker in India"));

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.v(TAG,"view click event");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        getCurrentLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        // mMap.clear();
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "onMarkerDragStart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "onMarkerDrag", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        // getting the Co-ordinates
        latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
        longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

        //move to current position
        moveMap();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "onMarkerClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: not working...still need to press send button in the emulator setting

Comment: I think onLocation change on getting called

Comment: So now what should i do?

Comment: use this link for better understanding http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/
above code is for location on map

Comment: Emulator need to send to receive. I got it. Thanks