# Why longitude and latitude cannot display on the textview?

Tags: android, location

Last time I put the code on oncreate method which can successfully capture the device longitude and latitude but currently I run again and it show nothing please anyone can advice me on this question?
original should be can found in last month but currently cannot found!

[image]
[image]

The code is like this.

```
lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000 , 0, (LocationListener) this);

    //get Location
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    la = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
    searchla.setText("Latitude: "+ la);

    lo = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    searchlo.setText("Longitude: "+lo);
```

so did i miss out something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293122/current-location-not-auto-display-to-the-textview

Comment: @LevonPetrosyan hey thats my question with the same code but currently cannot run><

Comment: Is there an error in the output console?

Comment: @chamathabeysinghe E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa2632260

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I would test to see if the longitude and latitude are returning values. Try putting break points and see.

If they are, it's problem for conversion and if not, it's problem with retrieval. Not the answer but gives the problem a direction to look into.

Comment: I suspected a problem with the conversion but I was wrong.

Comment: I don't quite understand what u want to say?

Comment: Before I make any more comments, just to clarify the second image is what your application is currently showing, right?

Comment: yes. thats the problem. I did successfully got the longitude and latitude before today but today got new version then I updated and then this problem suddenly came out. What happen?

Comment: What I am saying is you need to check if your longitude and latitude are populated before you covert them into string. If they are not populated, you would expect to see at least Longitude and latitude written in your textview

Comment: But im using emulator to run the apps which should automatically to show it because i set it inside the oncreate method.

Comment: First, I would suggest you to debug the application and  see if the longitude and latitude is populated or not.

Comment: E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb40fe4c0

Comment: I suspect something from research but tell me something. When you debug your application, is longitude and latitude populated?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other code places that affects visibility of textviews, the only part is permission scope. So the device has no permission and then it goes to out of scope.

Comment: But I did add the permission inside the manifest. This part got other code which is contain almost 400+ lines

Comment: Did you try debugging the line of  `searchla.setText("Latitude: "+ la);` ?

Comment: How to debug this line?

Comment: I meant did you reach the line when you debug it step by step

Comment: Nope. But it got one message. Emulator: eglMakeCurrent failed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it seems a dummy answer but can you check if the location service (GPS) is activated on the emulator?
On the second screen shot I do not see the Location On icon.
If this is not the case:
Since last time you (when it worked) have you switched the API version? It is the same emulator/settings?

EDIT: Marshmallow emulator problem - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37069061
Solution: update to a newer API version

Comment: Got this error cannot get the location. E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb40bef60

Comment: Provide answer not dummy la my friend. provide solution is already an action of hero. hahahaha

Comment: Are your Android OS running marshmallow? This can be a known bug [issueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37069061)

Comment: Try creating a new emulator using API 24+

Comment: It is not about getting the location. It's about writing to textView.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046375/e-surface-getslotfrombufferlocked-unknown-buffer-0xab7519c0

Comment: If you search for "E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer:" in Google you will find many non-location based issues and most of them links to the following issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37069061

Comment: Still can't. It looks like I got the new error code which in google can't found.

Comment: Have you added this feature?
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

Comment: add already. not working. But i'm using the emulator to run the application.